# Why is Nuget not including/finding beta versions

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I have a dependency in nuspec for "Bbb" defined like this

```
  <dependency id="Aaa" version="[7.5.0,7.5.1)" />
```

Build for "Aaa" built and deployed beta version of Aaa 7.5.0-beta498

Build for "Bbb" built and deployed beta version of Bbb 3.0.0-beta5

but when I try to install nuget package "Bbb" into 3rd project ("Ccc") I get this message

Unable to find a version of 'Aaa' that is compatible with 'Bbb 3.0.0-beta5 constraint: Aaa (≥ 7.5.0 && < 7.5.1)'.

Why?  I have checked include PreRelease in Nuget package manager. What is the syntax to include pre-releases for nuspec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-release NuGet packages are considered to be older versions than a stable release with the same major/minor/build version number.

Version 7.5.0-beta498 is considered to be below version 7.5.0 so it does not exist in the range ≥ 7.5.0 && < 7.5.1.

You will need to specify the pre-release as the lowest value in the constraint.